# Funny xlwings issue: script works in Python but not from Excel

Tags: python, excel, xlwings, file-not-found

I have written a program that reads all text files in a directory, loads them as tabular data into a dataframe, and then loads each dataframe into a new Excel worksheet in the same workbook. The intended purpose is to have the program be called from a button on a workbook that then loads all data in a directory.

The program runs fine in python with any directory and any text file...but not when called from within Excel.

This is the error that I get:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "h:\notebooks\augustine project\ramread.py", line 35, in data_reader clean_null_bytes(text_files) # Clean each file of null bytes
File "h:\notebooks\augustine project\ramread.py", line 76, in clean_null_bytes
with open(file, 'rb') as to_clean :
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1 KPA COLUMN 
BELOW REACTION TABLE.TXT'
```

So it is getting the correct path and filenames from that path but for some reason it seems that opening the files on the path is not working within Excel. Does Excel have a different way of interpreting a file path? I am really at a loss for next steps with this problem.

Any assistance or ideas is greatly appreciated.

Here is the program, below:

```
import os as os
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory,Tk
import pandas as pd

def main() :   
    Book = xl.Book.caller()
    data_dictionary  = data_reader()

    for title, table in data_dictionary.items() :
        Book.sheets.add(name = title)
        Book.sheets[title].range("B2").value = table

def data_reader() -> dict :
    folder = open_folder() # User selects folder on system
    text_files = get_txt_files(folder) # Generate a list of text files in folder
    clean_null_bytes(text_files) # Clean each file of null bytes
    data_dict = tables_for_export(text_files) # Read the cleaned files as dataframes in a dict

    return data_dict

def open_folder() -> str :
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.update
    folder = askdirectory()
    root.destroy()

    return folder

def get_txt_files(directory_path: str) -> list :
    all_files = os.listdir(directory_path)
    txt_files = [file for file in all_files if 
             (file[-4:] == ".txt") or   #check the last four chars in file name
             (file[-4:] == ".TXT")]

    return txt_files

def clean_null_bytes(list_of_txt_files: list) :
    for file in list_of_txt_files :
        with open(file, 'rb') as to_clean :
            raw_data = to_clean.read()
        clean_data = raw_data.replace(b'\x00', b'')
        with open(file, 'wb') as cleaned :
            cleaned.write(clean_data)      
    return

def tables_for_export(list_of_txt_files: list) -> dict :
    for_export = {}

    for file in list_of_txt_files :
        data_frame = pd.read_table(file)
        for_export.update({file[:-4] : data_frame})

    return for_export
```

Comment: Make sure you deal with absolute file paths: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/815

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, Felix. The relative vs absolute paths is the first thing that I double-checked when I got the problem but the path string from open_folder() is indeed the absolute path ("H:\Notebooks\...etc."), although I checked it when run from python (and did not try to print out the string in Excel). Do you think that when run from Excel that the code from tkinter could return a relative path instead of the absolute?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Felix Zumstein for keeping me stuck on the file path solution. The problem was indeed a file path problem.

I was getting the absolute file path from tkinter.askdirectory() and using it to generate a list of text files. I was then trying to open these text files **WITH JUST THE FILENAMES**. This worked in Python (probably because I was running the script in the same directory as the files) but not in Excel.

To fix the issue, I had to concatenate the directory path to the beginning of each filename in the list. Then I could open the files. Then I had to remove the path from the filenames afterwards to order to use the filenames as the names of worksheets in Excel.

Will post final code for completeness.